# static block doesn't show products in Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I need to show products in static block, but it does not display any product. when I write any content in static block then the content will appears. But category product will not display. I need to show product with pagination toolbar.

I tried with the code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="5" column_count="4" count="6" limit="4" mode="grid" toolbar_block_name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add "catalog/product_list" to the permissions: [ System > Permissions > Blocks ], otherwise the block won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

You might be adding the code in Visual mode in the static block. You need to add that code in text mode. You can do that on clicking the Show / Hide Editor and paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

**CE 1.9.2.2** includes all the changes from the [recent-patch](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details) [SUPEE-6788](https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788), one of which was restrict the blocks that can be used in CMS blocks, pages, emails (etc...) by default.

You can whitelist them through the admin under `System > Permissions > (Blocks | Variables).`